# Is there any way to install OpenCV in C++ on Windows without using any IDE but only in cmd?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, installation, configuration

I am writing a educational program about OpenCV in C++ right now. And as for the question about fee and copyright. I'm now thinking if there exists any way to install C++ OpenCV only with cmd or PowerShell ?
I have already found many ways in the Internet, but they all told me that I have to use VS or other IDE or I should use python OpenCV. But as for the classes I will teach, I must use C++, so I want to know if there exists any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes you can do this using CMake. opencv is built using CMake. You can see that by the `CMakeLists.txt` in the source code: [https://github.com/opencv/opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv)

Comment: @drescherjm That's really helpful! Thx

Comment: You download the official release package (which for Windows is a self-extracting executable) from the OpenCV website, and run it. That includes the source code, headers, 64bit libs and DLLs for current Visual C++ compilers, Python libraries and Java libraries. Unless you have some special requirements, this is sufficient, and there's no need to build it from scratch.

Comment: The problem is unclear. On which machine(s) do you want to install OpenCV? Which ones are lacking an IDE? The C++ program you develop can just ship the OpenCV DLL's in the same directory as your EXE, it doesn't require a special installation for end users. But "teach classes", that's presumably an OpenCV programming class. Why wouldn't they have Visual Studio?